# JQUERY Datatable search restrict to second column only

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've a jquery datatable in which the search feature I want to be focused on the first column only. I mean If I input something on the search box, it should search that text in a specific column alone. I tried with a belief it should make the searching only for the second column

```
var myTable = $("#tbl_main").dataTable({
    "dom": "<'tableinfobar'i><'tablesearchbox'f><'tablebody't><'tablelength'l><'tablepaging'p>",
    "ordering": false,
    "searching": false,
    "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": 1,
        "searchable": true
    }],
});
```

But it hides the search box completely

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer myself and posting it so if it helpful to someone having similar issue

```
var myTable = $("#tbl_main").dataTable({
    "dom": "<'tableinfobar'i><'tablesearchbox'f><'tablebody't><'tablelength'l><'tablepaging'p>",
    "ordering": false,
    "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": [0, 2, 3, 4],
        "searchable": false
    }],
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, 100, -1], [10, 20, 50, 100, "All"]],
    "language": {
        "search": "Search Person _INPUT_"
    }
});
```

THis will search the input text in second column only